# Component symbol not showing up in a Papyrus UML diagram

Tags: uml, tool-uml, papyrus

I am new to Papyrus. Few days ago I installed eclipse Kepler (Build id: 20130614-0229) with Papyrus 0.10.0v20130612

I created a model, then I added a component diagram. I added few components to the diagram and I saw that the shapes were simple rectangles. I was expecting the component symbol with two smaller rectangles on one side.

If I open the properties of one of them, I select appearance and I check the box "Element Icon" I can see a small component icon appearing beside the name, but I was trying to set the shape of the containing rectangle.

In the same view (Properties->Appearance) I tried to change the stereotype display from "Text" to "Icon" or "Text and Icon", but nothing happens. If I close and reopen the stereotype display is set back to text.

Is it possible to set the shape of a component type to the usual component symbol? How can I set it?

Does the "stereotype display" select box have anything to do with it? In this case do I have to do something else to make it work?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Hi @goth! very good question, I also have the same problem with stereotype display and I hope to learn how this problem can be managed .I will tell you how when I know the solution

Answer (score 1):

Hello I know that is a little bit late for you, but I faced the same issue and I would like to share the solution so in the future someone can save time solving it.
To display the second box below the title (so called packed elements compartment) just:

```
right click on the component -> Filters -> Show/Hide Compartments -> packaged elements
```

You can also click on the component, type the shortcut `Ctrl + F6` and select the compartments you want to display.